# 'Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1' error with pandas dataframe by operating two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe - for the purpose of sample data every day has only 10 minutes:

```
                Date    Close
0   2019-06-20 07:00:00 2927.25
1   2019-06-20 07:05:00 2927.00
2   2019-06-20 07:10:00 2926.75
183 2019-06-21 07:00:00 2932.25
184 2019-06-21 07:05:00 2932.25
185 2019-06-21 07:10:00 2931.00
366 2019-06-24 07:00:00 2941.75
367 2019-06-24 07:05:00 2942.25
368 2019-06-24 07:10:00 2941.50
549 2019-06-25 07:00:00 2925.50
550 2019-06-25 07:05:00 2926.50
551 2019-06-25 07:10:00 2926.50
732 2019-06-26 07:00:00 2903.25
```

I want to get the daily range of the closing price.
I grouped the data by day and get the min max of close:

```
rangeofday = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1D')).agg({'Close':[np.min, np.max]})
rangeofday = rangeofday.dropna()

            Close
            amin    amax
Date        
2019-06-20  2926.75 2927.25
2019-06-21  2931.00 2932.25
2019-06-24  2941.50 2942.25
2019-06-25  2925.50 2926.50
2019-06-26  2903.25 2904.00
... ... ...
```

So far so good, but what happens is that the names of the columns are weird, and somehow not accessible by name.

```
    rangeofday.amin
or
    rangeofday.Closeamin

    = 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'amin'
```

So I can access them with iloc:

```
rangeofday.iloc[:, [1]]

            Close
            amax
Date    
2019-06-20  2927.25
2019-06-21  2932.25
2019-06-24  2942.25
2019-06-25  2926.50
```

Now I try to subtract min from max:

```
rangeofday['range'] = (rangeofday.iloc[:, [0]] - rangeofday.iloc[:, [1]])/0.25
```

and get the error:

```
Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

What does this mean and how can get around this error?

Comment: It's a multi index: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html, e.g. `rangeofday.loc[:, ('Close', 'amin')]`

Comment: @r.ook this helps a lot, and works! thank you

Comment: should I delete the question as this is solved?

Comment: I posted my solution as an answer for now.  You might close the question by accepting the current solution.  If a better answer comes along, please feel free to accept the one that is most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you applied multiple `agg` functions, `pandas` automatically applied a `MultiIndex` to your grouped frame.  See more details: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

In particular, if you want to access the columns, you can access by passing the column names as a `tuple`:

`rangeofday[('Close', 'amax')]`

or

`rangeofday.loc[:, ('Close', 'amin')]`